# Transitive actions of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ on itself

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Two actions of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ on itself that we naturally might consider are $\overline{m} \cdot \overline{n} = \overline{m}+\overline{n}$, and $\overline{m} \cdot \overline{n} = \overline{n}-\overline{m}$. In fact these actions are isomorphic. On the other hand, we can define an action such as $\overline{m} \cdot \overline{n} = 2\overline{m} + \overline{n}$, which is not isomorphic to those.

So my question is whether all the *transitive* actions of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ acting on itself are isomorphic to the above $\overline{m} \cdot \overline{n} = \overline{m}+\overline{n}$.

Comment: What's the definition of isomorphic *actions*?

Comment: Yes, this is the regular action.

Comment: @user750041 Actions of $G$ on $A$ and $G$ on $B$ (where here $G = A = B = \mathbb{Z}_6$) are considered to be isomorphic if there is a bijection $\phi \colon A \to B$ which is a morphism of $G$-sets, i.e. $\phi(g \cdot a) = g \cdot \phi(a)$.

Comment: @Derek Holt could you elaborate please, what is the proof that all the transitive actions are isomorphic to it?

Comment: Giving an action of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ on itself is equivalent to giving a permutation in $S_6$ whose order divides $6$. The action will be faithful if the order is _exactly_ $6$.

Comment: @Geoffrey Trang how does faithful relate to transitive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $\mathbb{Z}_6$ acts on itself in some way. Then, in order for the action to be transitive, the map $\bar{m} \mapsto \bar{m} \cdot \bar{0}$ (which is easily seen to be an equivariant map, if the codomain has the given action and the domain has the "natural" action given by addition) must be surjective. Since it is a surjective map from a finite set to itself, it must also be injective, and hence an isomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_6$-sets.